# r - Conditionally subtract two data tables

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, subtraction

I have two data.tables showing temperatures for multiple locations (identified by geocode).

I would like to create a third one based on a subtraction of them. Here they are:

```
library(data.table)

# Generate random data:
geocode <- paste0("N", 1:10)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2004-12-31"), by="month")
models <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
temp <- runif(length(geocode)*length(dates)*length(models), min=0, max=30)
dt1 <- data.table(expand.grid(Location=geocode,Date=dates,Model=models),Temperature=temp)


ref <- runif(length(geocode), min=0, max=30)
dt2 <- data.table(expand.grid(Location=geocode), Temperature=ref)
```

I would like to conditionally subtract dt2 from dt1. By each location (geocode), I would like to subtract temperature in dt2 from temperature in dt1, preserving the other columns (`Date` and `Model`).

How to achieve this? I would know how to do if it was a single data table, but I've never tried to do algebra on two different data tables like this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this works:

```
dt1[dt2, on=.(Location), td := x.Temperature - i.Temperature, by=.EACHI]

      Location       Date Model Temperature          td
   1:       N1 2000-01-01     A    3.949276 -19.2110455
   2:       N2 2000-01-01     A    2.811684 -11.6405195
   3:       N3 2000-01-01     A   24.069659  13.6159779
   4:       N4 2000-01-01     A   25.809426  -1.8793405
   5:       N5 2000-01-01     A   25.193624  19.6812965
  ---                                                  
2996:       N6 2004-12-01     E   24.298463   4.0218859
2997:       N7 2004-12-01     E    1.488011 -26.4472283
2998:       N8 2004-12-01     E   27.489108   5.6525076
2999:       N9 2004-12-01     E    3.487664  -5.9926003
3000:      N10 2004-12-01     E    8.523718  -0.7559126
```

Checking by eye...

```
dt2[dt1[1:5], on=.(Location), .(Location, t1 = i.Temperature, t2 = x.Temperature)]

   Location        t1        t2
1:       N1  3.949276 23.160321
2:       N2  2.811684 14.452204
3:       N3 24.069659 10.453681
4:       N4 25.809426 27.688766
5:       N5 25.193624  5.512328
```

Looks right to me.

---

*How it works*

The syntax for an update join is `x[i, v := expr, by=.EACHI]`. Inside the expression, prefixes `i.*` and `x.*` can be used to clarify where columns are being taken from.

The `by=.EACHI` might not be needed, but I usually use it for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does what I need! And thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 3):

`merge` (`left_join`), then `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dt3 <- left_join(dt1, dt2, by="Location") %>%
          mutate(desired=Temperature.x-Temperature.y)
```

#### Output

```
  Location       Date Model Temperature.x Temperature.y     desired
1       N1 2000-01-01     A      4.158847     17.531085 -13.3722373
2       N2 2000-01-01     A      9.644764     23.184142 -13.5393783
3       N3 2000-01-01     A      4.644948     20.946587 -16.3016384
4       N4 2000-01-01     A      3.966845     25.232795 -21.2659502
5       N5 2000-01-01     A      6.639178     29.325365 -22.6861873
6       N6 2000-01-01     A      6.791424      6.957811  -0.1663875
```

To unselect Temperature.x and Temperature.y

```
dt3 <- dt3 %>% select(-Temperature.x, -Temperature.y)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the first answer, which by the way works fine! However, I need to stick to the `data.table` solution because I still have more operation to perform on the data set and I am not very familiar with `dplyr`...

Comment: Not a problem. I upvoted the `data.table` solution as well.